# Having more than one plot twist?

Tags: plot

I have this scenario that none of the characters knew about previous to the actual encounter. Does that count as a plot twist, or just Dramatic Irony?

Either way, I think of it as a plot twist, something to keep the story interesting. But I have another one plotted out in the near future, so does the  first one count as a twist, or just a plot mover?

> After they left the hospital, and a robotic arm replaced Liam’s original one, they had to get Liam registered as a legal cyborg. The paperwork was tedious and long, but it got done and they were finally able to go home. KoKo demanded to take a look at the wound and put Liam on heavy painkillers, which Greyson agreed to.
>
> Liam’s prosthetic arm was working properly and wasn’t causing him any big problems, which was a huge relief to both Greyson and KoKo. 
>   While KoKo took care of Liam and acted like the house mother, May dedicated most of her time training the chimeras to do tricks so she can sell them.
>
> With nothing to do, Haku took the chore of exterior design, and lifted the sloping roof, repainted, and replaced the decks boards with wood that he cut out of the forest near the house. This happened fairly quickly and only took him a few hours to complete. Haku wiped his forehead on his arm, removing the majority of the sweat that culminated there. His ears picked up a distant noise and he swerved on his heels, making a full 180 turn.
>
> Motorized humming emanated from the East and several hover scooters rode up to the house. The guy in the front dismounted his scooter and lifted his visor up, his face was completely alien. Haku got a closer look at him as he confidently strode up to where Haku was. His features were all off, they were pointed and sharp, and his eyes were too...discolored. They were a bright turquoise that were filled with life. Haku was skeptical and pressed a button on his watch, notifying KoKo that something was wrong.
>
> “Cute house,” the man said, almost sarcastically. His voice was soft and angelic. It filled Haku with dread, though, because he knew that wasn’t an ordinary human quality.
>
> “What are you?” Haku asked, not caring that it was inconsiderate to ask someone that question.
>
> “I’m really glad you asked that, human.” The man started, he took his helmet completely off now. He had ears that were pointed at the top, not in a ‘birth defect’ sort of way. “I am what you would call an Elf, young one. I am Prince Vincent.” He bowed towards the very confused Haku.
>
> “I come from my home planet, Morbus, to reactivate our intergalactic contract. 
>   It was a lawfully bound promise to keep each other thriving. Your NOVA went back on their word to help us, and now my home is dying,” as the man was speaking Haku had noticed a hint of fangs in the stranger’s mouth, his hair was the same color as his eyes - which looked reptilian.
>
> Haku had a memory of his father mentioning NOVA one time. Apparently, they once controlled the workforce and careers of able citizens around the world. They were also the lead sponsors for the earliest space explorations. That will explain why there are otherworldlies here. NOVA disbanded several years ago, and Haku was assuming they didn’t tell their people to broadcast the message.
>
> “Prince Vincent - was it?” Haku began, “NOVA disbanded years ago… so there is no contract.” The air seemed to still around the two and KoKo came to meet Haku from the back yard. She had a wrench in one hand and a pistol in the other, probably Haku’s fathers. The comment stirred something in Vince and he narrowed his eyes, calculating a proper response to give to the boy.
>
> The woman standing next to the kid looked like a threat. Vince snapped his fingers and two guards dismounted their scooters and jogged up to detain her. 
>   “Whoa, what do you think you’re doing?” She backed away from the guards touch and raised her weapons.
>
> “You pose a threat to the Prince, you must be detained, for His Majesty's safety,” one of the guards shot back, taking the weapons and holding her arms back. Vince was pleased with himself and smiled a venomous smile.
>   Haku didn’t like him suddenly.
>
> Vince looked down at the human before him and noticed that something was off about him. “What’s your name, child?”
>
> “Haku Amone,” replied Haku.
>
> “Pleasure,” Vince said, holding his hand out to shake. Haku gripped it and shook one firm shake. The smile was still plastered on his face when he carefully pulled his gloves off, one digit at a time. “So there is no NOVA, and no contract… Who, may I ask, is running the world?”
>
> Haku lifted an eyebrow and pursed his lips. “Our planet doesn’t run like yours does, your Majesty,” Haku emphasized the title, indicating that it isn’t customary to have royalty on Earth. “We have individual sections of the planet, run by different people in differing degrees of power.” Haku hesitated before continuing. “This country is without a leader…”
>
> Vince’s ears twitched and his mind raced with a plan. Since this large portion of land is leaderless, he could rule it. This made his initial plan so much simpler.
>
> With faux sympathy Vince said, “I see, I couldn’t imagine the horrors of having such a lack of order in my country.” He paused to glimpse at the small house in front of him. “My people and I would love to help you restore balance here.”
>
> Haku knew what he was proposing by that devious smile splayed on his face, but this could be a huge opportunity. “I’ll be right back, Sir. I have to grab someone real quick.” He went around to the back of the house without waiting for an answer, a pang of guilt hit his heart as he left KoKo out there with them alone.
>
> He reached the secret door to the cages, where he last saw his dad. He spotted him sitting on an operating table with a book in his hands. “Dad, Elves.” Haku said in between breaths. Greyson understood exactly what he was saying and closed his book immediately. “Guards…. They have KoKo, dad!”
>
> Greyson bolted up the steps to the trap door and smashed them open, Haku close behind. When they reached the front, the prince stopped what he was doing and his ears dropped.
>
> “Son, of, man…. Sir Greyson?” Vince gasped. Haku was genuinely confused at this point, if he wasn’t before, he definitely was now.
>
> Greyson looked unamused when he saw the prince and placed a hand on his hip. “What the hell are you doing here, Vincent?” He asked this as if he were an old friend.
>
> “I was here to re-activate our contract with NOVA, but it seems here that they’re all dead now,” Vince stated simply. Greyson snapped his fingers and the guards holding KoKo let her go and shoved her over to Haku.
>
> “You two, go inside, now please,” he instructed. Haku and KoKo obeyed immediately.
>
> “Well, now that you know they’re dead, what are you still doing here?” Greyson was impatient with Vince, he didn’t want to be alone with him if at all necessary.
>
> Vince chuckled beautifully and moved his loose bangs out of his right eye, “My planet is dying, Greyson. You know exactly why, too.”
>   Indeed he did know, there was only a matter of time before the elves mined right through their planet’s core and they will implode on themselves.

This is the first  written plot twist, it expands on my idea of the main villain stumbling upon the protagonist's house, and the protagonist's father used to work for the villain many years previous. The villain recognizes him and tries to be buddies again, but the protagonist didn't know about their relationship.

The next one will be "the villain isn't as great as he is portrayed in the beginning".

Comment: I really don't understand what the point of your question is. Does it matter what it is called?

Comment: @Cloudchaser I was wondering if I could use more than two plot twists, and then I gave an example of my first one.

Comment: You don't have to provide the entire plot twist scene, you can just summarize it for us. In fact, that would be preferable, so that I don't have to scroll down three pages to see the remainder of your question.

Comment: I have provided a new answer under the duplicate question. I think knowing the specifics of your story is unnecessary to answer your question, but if my answer is not sufficient, please comment under it and I'll try to address your concerns.